# Android: Path with two or more pre-defined path segments wont fill correctly (addPath)

Tags: android, canvas, path, shader

I am trying to define a custom shape with a Path object that I want to fill with a bitmap shader. I would like to define this Path by using previously defined Path objects, with the addPath method. The problem is that if I have more than one Path object added to my contour Path then the path wont fill correctly (or at all). I am using SDK 15 as a minimum.

I created a simplified version of my code:

```
  contourPath = new Path();

    Path segment1 = new Path();
    Path segment2 = new Path();
    Path segment3 = new Path();
    Path segment4 = new Path();

    segment1.moveTo(0,0);
    segment1.lineTo(width, 0);

    segment2.moveTo(width, 0);
    segment2.lineTo(width, height);

    segment3.moveTo(width, height);
    segment3.lineTo(0, height);

    segment4.moveTo(0, height);
    segment4.lineTo(0, 0);

    contourPath.addPath(segment1);
    contourPath.addPath(segment2);
    contourPath.addPath(segment3);
    contourPath.addPath(segment4);

    Paint fillPaint = new Paint();
    fillPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    fillPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    try {
        canvas.drawPath(contourPath, fillPaint);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "nope" );
    }
```

And this is the result I get:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpLnw.jpg)

Of course the path I am working on much more detailed, so although it could be created as one Path in one go, It would be a very long "spagethi" code and it would create a lot of problems, so I would only do that if there was absolutely no other option.

Is there any way to make this work?